# Django creating relation

Tags: python, django

How can I add  several different category to  `News`?

```
class Categories(models.Model):

title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
c_date = models.DateTimeField('date published')
url_code =models.URLField()
def __unicode__(self): return self.title



class News(models.Model):
title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
content= models.TextField()
categories = models.ForeignKey(Categories)  
c_date = models.DateTimeField('date published')    
      image =models.ImageField(upload_to = 'img/', 
          default ='img/None/no-img.jpg')    
url_code =models.URLField()

def __unicode__(self): return self.title
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right now, you can only have one category per news item; because your database relationship is defined as one-to-one.

To make it so that a news item can have more than one category, change the relationship to [ManyToMany](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/).

```
class News(models.Model):
    categories = models.ManyToManyField(Category)
```

Now, to add categories to news:

```
n = News()
c = Category.objects.get(pk=1) # fetch one category
n.save() # Save the news item first
n.categories.add(c) # add the category for the news item
c = Category.objects.get(pk=2) # fetch another
n.categories.add(c)
n.save()
```

To fetch each Category, then all the news item tagged with that category:

```
c = Category.objects.all()
for category in c:
   for news in category.news_set.all():
       print(news)
```

Comment: news is added by django admin so where i must input that code, sorry i'm new in django

Comment: sorry one more question what is pk and why  just two categories is added to news, thanks

Comment: Its an example - read the tutorial please as your questions are very basic and answered in the tutorial.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [`ManyToManyField`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ManyToManyField):

```
class News(models.Model):
    ....
    categories = models.ManyToManyField(Categories)
```

**UPDATE**: To output the list of categories use the following code:

```
{% for news in news_list %}
    <h4>{{ news.title }}</h4>
    <div>
        Categories:
        {% for category in news.categories.all %}
            {{ category.title }}
        {% endfor %}
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: not working when i try to display categories i have news_list.Categories.None

Comment: To display categories use the `news.categories.all()` queryset.  See the update in my answer.

Comment: Category is a menu of my site and when i choose some category i must see news for this category, anyway thanks